# Convert 4 byte unsigned ints to 0-127

Tags: integer, range

I need to convert a range of values I receive from another software.

They come in the from of 4 byte integers (0 - 0xFFFFFFFF) but I want to display them as a range of 0-127.

I'm not familiar with how unsigned ints work. When I tried setting the value to 127 from inside the software I get a reading of "-16" value in my application.

Could you please give me an explanation of how this works or give me some relevant resources to study?

I'd prefer language agnostic answers but I happen to use Javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, a 4 byte integer can contain values spanning a range of over 4 billion. It is not clear as to how you intend to represent these with a range of 0-127. If the values coming from the other program can be guaranteed to always be in the range 0-127 then that of course, won't be an issue. However you will need to consider what happens when larger values (or negative values) are received.

Secondly, an integer can be signed or unsigned. An 8 bit variable (one byte) can have the signed range -128 through 127 or the unsigned range 0 through 255. (This may represent actual numbers, or maybe an ASCII character or a bit-field or any other number of things. You must know ahead of time what the value represents and if it is signed or unsigned.)

Let's assume it simply represents a number. If it is a signed number then the most significant bit will be set for negative numbers and cleared for positive numbers. For unsigned integers, the most significant bit is just the same as any other bit.

Staying with the 8-bit byte, a value of 0b10000001 would be: 
unsigned: 129 
signed: -127 
A value of 0b00000001 will always be 1 whether the value is signed or unsigned. There will be plenty of tutorials on the internet that discuss this subject.

Thirdly, you will need to know if the 4 bytes you are receiving are "little-endian" or "big-endian". In other words, when you get the first byte, is this the most significant byte or the least significant byte? If you get this around the wrong way then the resulting number will be meaningless.

Before any meaningful answer can be given you will need to provide much more information. Nonetheless, I hope I have been able to point you in the right direction.

Comment: I know the app is sending big endian numbers (network byte order).
They numbers are always in the range of 0-127. In this case they also are rounded in steps (so only integers, can't have decimals in the value I want to display) I also know that they are unsigned.

Comment: If it's big-endian then, if you look at each byte coming in (print it or view it in a debugger), for a value of 127 you should see 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x7F. If you are getting anything other than the above then, either the originating program is not sending the data as a four byte integer **or** you are not reading that data correctly in your program. If you can post the relevant part of your source code then we can have a look to see if there's any obvious errors.

Comment: The incoming numbers are hex based looking something like < Buffer (..other stuff) b5 04 f3 34> last 4 bytes of the packet are the value. What I'm getting is the signed 2's complement apparently. I checked the values on an converter site hex -> decimal and I know at least that the library I use decodes the buffers correctly. Now how do I make those values human readable? for example if the value from the software is 127 I get < ff ff ff f0 > = -16 two's complement.

Comment: <FF FF FF F0> is definitely -16 decimal. So it appears you are actually interpreting the received data according to the standard method. I cannot determine how 127 could ever get encoded as FF FF FF F0. Either the software generating the value is incorrect or they are using some non-standard binary encoding technique. I suggest sending a value of zero, then 1, then 2 and so on to see if there is any pattern in the data that you receive. Then you may be able to determine their encoding method.

Comment: Thanks! I think I got it. All I had to do is get the value of 1 which was 33818640 and then divide the values with that number. I won't pretend I understand how that division works but it works.. I checked all values from 0 to 127 and they worked.

Comment: Well done. B.T.W. the value 33818640 has the hex value <02 04 08 10> so there is a pattern there though, on the surface, it does seem a bit strange. Using that logic, though, it might be simpler just to read the first byte and divide by two (or shift right 1 bit) rather than read all four bytes and divide by 33818640. Thanks for accepting the answer.